# How to convert the date integer value of ACF plugin in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the jQuery Date Picker of WordPress **ACF Plugin** to make a custom Meta Box of a custom POST.

Now, when this Date Picker value is saved to the database table called **xxx_postmeta** I see that value is:

**20190630**

[image]

So then when I get that meta value using below code:

```
<?php echo date('F j, Y ',  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'article_1_pub_date', true)) ; ?>
```

then the date is showing wrong, Like this:

**August 22, 1970**

Is there any wrong or ACF issue?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the date you saved is **June 30, 2019**. You can’t use PHP date() function on this string.

Convert to a date object and print:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20190630');
echo $date->format('F j, Y ');
```